# What is a good way to interact with iframe elements using Selenium IDE?

Tags: javascript, integration-testing, fckeditor, selenium-ide

I am wanting to test a web application which uses [FCKeditor](http://ckeditor.com/) in [Selenium IDE](http://seleniumhq.org/projects/ide/).  Unfortunately, FCKeditor uses iframes, which are difficult to test in Selenium IDE.  Basically, all I want to do is set the value of the FCKeditor editing area and read it later to see if the value was submitted correctly.

I suppose this question is two-fold:  first of all, does anyone have an FCKeditor-specific solution to this problem?  and secondly, does anyone know of a good way to implement custom Javascript functions that can be used in your tests in Selenium IDE?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have come up with a solution.  It involves using Selenium IDE's `storeEval` method, `storedVars` variable, and anonymous functions.  It also exploits the `activeElement` property of the `iframe`s.

Basically, what I do is call the `storeEval` method with javascript to set a certain element of `storedVars` to the function I will use later as the argument.  For the `FCKeditor` example the argument would be:

```
storedVars["setFCKeditorField"] = function (fieldName, value) {var iframe = this.browserbot.findElement("id="+fieldName+"___Frame"); var outerDocument = iframe.contentDocument; var innerDocument = outerDocument.activeElement.contentDocument; var textField = innerDocument.activeElement; textField.innerHTML = value;}
```

I have formatted it like that on purpose because that is the way it would show up in Selenium IDE, and I it is obviously less than ideal.

Then, later, when I actually want to set the value of the FCKeditor field, I call `storeEval` again with javascript to call the function as the argument, like so:

```
storedVars["setFCKeditorField"].call(this, "SU_ats_subscription_configuration_model[subscription_reminder_message]", "Subscription Expiring Message.<br/>");
```

This works, but I am hoping there is a better way.  Would Selenium RC make this easy?